# How to read a text file in Python

Tags: python, file, output, repeat

I have an assignment that reads:

> Write a function which takes the input file name and list of words
>   and write into the file “Repeated_word.txt” the word and number of
>   times word repeated in input file?

```
word_list = [‘Emma’, ‘Woodhouse’, ‘father’, ‘Taylor’, ‘Miss’, ‘been’, ‘she’, ‘her’]
```

**My code is below.**

All it does is create the new file `'Repeated_word.txt'` however it doesn't write the number of times the word from the wordlist appears in the file.

---

```
#obtain the name of the file
filename = raw_input("What is the file being used?: ")
fin = open(filename, "r")


#create list of words to see if repeated
word_list = ["Emma", "Woodhouse", "father", "Taylor", "Miss", "been", "she", "her"]

def repeatedWords(fin, word_list):
    #open the file
    fin = open(filename, "r")
    #create output file
    fout = open("Repeated_word.txt", "w")
    #loop through each word of the file
    for line in fin:
        #split the lines into words
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            #check if word in words is equal to a word from word_list
            for i in range(len(word_list)):
                if word == i:
                    #count number of times word is in word
                    count = words.count(word)
                    fout.write(word, count)
    fout.close

repeatedWords(fin, word_list)
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: It is supposed to read through the file, counting how many times each word from word_list is used and put that information into a new file. My new file looks like 'Emma1her4been2her4her4her4been2Miss3Taylor2been2Miss3Taylor2her3her3been2Emma1she1Miss3her3her2her2Taylor1Miss1Emma1her1father2father2she2she2her6she4Miss1Taylor1her6she4she4her6she4her6her6her6been1she1her1'

Answer (score 1):

These lines,

```
        for i in range(len(word_list)):
            if word == i:
```

should be

```
        for i in range(len(word_list)):
            if word == word_list[i]:
```

or

```
        for i in word_list:
            if word == i:
```

`word` is a string, whereas `i` is an integer, the way you have it right now. These are never equal, hence nothing ever gets written to the file.

---

In response to your further question, you can either 1) use a dictionary to keep track of how many of each word you have, or 2) read in the whole file at once. This is one way you might do that:

```
words = fin.read().split()
for word in word_list:
    fout.write(word, words.count(word), '\n')
```

I leave it up to you to figure out where to put this in your code and what you need to replace. This is, after all, *your* assignment, not ours.

Comment: Thank you, now I have a new file however the output is
    Emma1her4been2her4her4her4been2Miss3Taylor2been2Miss3Taylor2her3her3been2Emma1she1Miss3her3her2her2Taylor1Miss1Emma1her1father2father2she2she2her6she4Miss1Taylor1her6she4she4her6she4her6her6her6been1she1her1

Do you know how to make it look like 

Emma 4 times
Woodhouse 2 times

etc

Comment: Thank you El'endia, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are making several mistakes here:

```
  [1]  for i in range(len(word_list)):
  [2]      if word == i:
  [3]          #count number of times word is in word
  [4]          count = words.count(word)
  [5]          fout.write(word, count)
```

First, you are comparing the `word` from `cin` with an integer from the range. [line 2]

Then you are writing the count to `fout` upon every match per line. [line 5] I guess you should keep the counts (e.g. in a dict) and write them all at the end of parsing input file.